# JMockit - Mock response InputStream is being read by JMockit

Tags: java, jmockit

I've got a method that I'm mocking to avoid making network calls during my unit tests, which looks something like this:

```
InputStream sendRequestAndReturnResponseStream(String param1, Map<String, String> param2)
```

I've mocked it in JMockit using the following:

```
final InputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("MyTestString".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
new NonStrictExpectations()
{
  {
    mockHttpClient.sendRequestAndReturnResponseStream(anyString, null);
    result = byteStream;
  }
};
```

When I create the ByteArrayInputStream in my test code before giving it to the NonStrictExpectation, its internal *pos* field is set to 0, which I would expect since it hasn't been written. When JMockit returns that result from the mocked method, however, the *pos* field inside the object is set to the size of the stream, making it seem that the array has already been read, presumably by something within JMockit.

This seems a strange behavior for the internal mutable state of an object to be changed between definition in the test code and return to the calling code by JMockit. Does JMockit actually read this InputStream before it gives it to my code? If so, is there a way to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem (using JMockit 1.27). The following test passes:

```
public class ExampleTest
{
    static class HttpClient {
        InputStream sendRequestAndReturnResponseStream(
            String param1, Map<String, String> param2) { return null; }
    }

    @Test
    public void returnUnchangedByteArrayInputStream(
        @Mocked final HttpClient mockHttpClient
    ) throws Exception {
        final InputStream byteStream = 
            new ByteArrayInputStream("MyTestString".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        int originalCountMinusPos = byteStream.available(); // = 12 (count) - 0 (pos) = 12

        new Expectations() {{
            mockHttpClient.sendRequestAndReturnResponseStream(anyString, null);
            result = byteStream;
        }};

        InputStream result = mockHttpClient.sendRequestAndReturnResponseStream("", null);
        int currentCountMinusPos = result.available(); // different iif pos changed

        assertSame(byteStream, result);
        assertEquals(originalCountMinusPos, currentCountMinusPos);
    }
}
```